# What can I do to customize a widget provided with this plugin? from where have I to start?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, widgets, customization

I am using this WordPress plugin to create an immage gallery: http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-media-gallery/

This plugin provide a single widget inside it and I would customize some litle function provided by this plugin but I don't know from where I have to start.

So I think that I have to modify some file into **includes** folder.

Can you help me to understand from where I have to start and how identify the widget code?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: if you will tell us WHAT you want to change, it will be easier to help you. is it the CSS ? the inner logic ? the form ? the update ? the defaults ??

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can search for the word "widget" in the code. WP_Widget is also a good candidate as it is the class that widgets are supposed to inherit.